# akka streams how to handle multipe source that it self produce source

Tags: akka-stream

Hi i have a sitiation where there is a Source which it self produce Sources. The number of source that would be produced is not know in advanced. is there a proper design pattern to handle this case. Basically it would look like Source ----->Multiple Sources ------->Sink

**EDIT**

The Scenario for this is as follows.

1. Create a Source out of a database iterator
2. For each data base  file provided by the above source transform the file to a Source
3. Attach those dynamically created source to a file IO sink

Basically i want bunch of data base content to be written to separate files via streams with back pressuring

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Source` of Sources:

```
type Data = ???

val sos : Source[Source[Data, _], _] = ???
```

Each of the `Data` Sources can be drained into individual File Sinks using [`Source.runForeach`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#runForeach(f:Out=%3EUnit)(implicitmaterializer:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]).

We first need a function that can generate the `Path` that you want the data written to:

```
val pathCreator : () => Path = ???
```

And a way of converting `Data` to `ByteString`:

```
val dataToByteString : Data => ByteString = ???
```

These functions can finally be combined to get the behavior you're looking for:

```
val drainSourceToFile : Source[Data, _] => Future[IOResult] = 
  _.map(dataToByteString)
   .to(FileIO.toPath(pathCreator()))
   .run()

sos runForeach drainSourceToFile
```

If you want all of the `IOResult` values from `FileIO.toPath` so that you can know whether the writing was successful then you'll need a slightly more complicated setup:

```
val allIOResults : Future[Seq[IOResult]] = 
  sos.map(drainSourceToFile)
     .to(Sink.seq)
     .run()
     .flatMap(Future.sequence)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think if i use a file IO sink all the sources will be written to a single file right? I want separate files. I have updated the question explain the scenario where this is needed

Comment: @user119020 I have updated my answer according to the updated specifications.

Comment: thanks again for the updated answer. But if i may ask given your implementation is there are way to short circuit and stop the execution if one of operations fails.

Comment: @user119020 This would require draining each file `Source` one-at-a-time.  In which case you don't need a Source of Source values, you probably need an `Iterator` of Source values instead and do a foreach on the Iterator.